# Unexpected end of file php

Tags: php

I had been getting an "expected Boolean" error, but this seems to be taking precedence and I can't see why the end of the file is unexpected (I'm very very new to this!)

Can anyone out there in the wide wide world of the internet see what I'm doing wrong?

```
//this is what's going on

<?php

//connect to the server

$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'classicmodels';

//connect to the database

$db = new mysqli ('localhost', $user, $pass, $db) or die ("Can't connect to database, please try again!");

//query the database

{

mysql_select_db("classicmodels");

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM classicmodels";

//display selected results from database

        WHILE($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)):

        $productCode =$rows['productCode'];
        $productName =$rows['productName'];
        $productLine =$rows['productLine'];
        $productScale =$rows['productScale'];
        $productVendor =$rows['productVendor'];
        $productDescription =$rows['productDescription'];
        $quantityInStock =$rows['quantityInStock'];
        $buyPrice = $rows['buyPrice'];
        $sellingPrice =$rows['sellingPrice'];



        echo "$productName $productDescription $sellingPrice $quantityInStock";





?>
```

//what's the problem?

I've been at this for over two hours now and I keep getting the same two errors, it's either "expected Boolean" or "unexpected end" - as far as I can tell the end is right there where I can see it but obviously I've overlooked something glaringly obvious!

Help me, Obi Wan Kenobis. You're my only hope.

Comment: You're missing your `endwhile;`

Comment: Where is your query ? Looks like you are fetching nothing.

Comment: Slap that code into a worthy IDE, *I say.*

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be missing the end of your while loop.

```
//this is what's going on

<?php

//connect to the server

$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'classicmodels';

//connect to the database

$db = new mysqli ('localhost', $user, $pass, $db) or die ("Can't connect to database, please try again!");

//query the database

{

mysql_select_db("classicmodels");

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM classicmodels";

//display selected results from database

        WHILE($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $productCode =$rows['productCode'];
            $productName =$rows['productName'];
            $productLine =$rows['productLine'];
            $productScale =$rows['productScale'];
            $productVendor =$rows['productVendor'];
            $productDescription =$rows['productDescription'];
            $quantityInStock =$rows['quantityInStock'];
            $buyPrice = $rows['buyPrice'];
            $sellingPrice =$rows['sellingPrice'];

            echo "$productName $productDescription $sellingPrice $quantityInStock";
        }



?>
```

I recommend using `{` and `}` instead of `:` because it's easier to see where your blocks of text start and end.

Answer (score 0):

Close your "while" with "endwhile"

```
 <?php

//connect to the server

$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'classicmodels';

//connect to the database

$db = new mysqli ('localhost', $user, $pass, $db) or die ("Can't connect to database, please try again!");

//query the database
mysql_select_db("classicmodels");

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM classicmodels";

//display selected results from database

        WHILE($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)):

        $productCode =$rows['productCode'];
        $productName =$rows['productName'];
        $productLine =$rows['productLine'];
        $productScale =$rows['productScale'];
        $productVendor =$rows['productVendor'];
        $productDescription =$rows['productDescription'];
        $quantityInStock =$rows['quantityInStock'];
        $buyPrice = $rows['buyPrice'];
        $sellingPrice =$rows['sellingPrice'];



        echo "$productName $productDescription $sellingPrice $quantityInStock";

      endwhile;



?>
```

Comment: Note that the unmatched { after `// query the database` was removed, too.

Comment: yeah! thanks for spotting that ^_^

Comment: OP's mistake, not yours (unless you accidentally erased it!).